# Kentico culture error when uploading a file

Tags: kentico

This only happens when using IE. An admin tries to upload a PDF in IE and we get this error.

> An error occurred when saving data. Please see event log for more
>   details. Message: [TreeNode.InsertInternal]: Document culture 'en-CA'
>   is not allowed on site 'KFFIntranet'.
>
> Exception type: System.Exception Stack Trace:  at
>   CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode.InsertInternal(TreeNode parent) at
>   CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode.Insert(TreeNode parent, Boolean
>   useDocumentHelper) at
>   CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentHelper.InsertDocument(TreeNode node,
>   TreeNode parentNode, TreeProvider tree, Boolean allowCheckOut) at
>   CMSModules_Content_CMSDesk_New_NewFile.ProcessDirectUploader() in
>   d:\Build\1\CMS\Intranet_Trunk\Sources\CMS\CMSModules\Content\CMSDesk\New\NewFile.aspx.cs:line 470 at
>   CMSModules_Content_CMSDesk_New_NewFile.DocumentManager_OnSaveData(Object
>   sender, DocumentManagerEventArgs e) in
>   d:\Build\1\CMS\Intranet_Trunk\Sources\CMS\CMSModules\Content\CMSDesk\New\NewFile.aspx.cs:line 313 at
>   CMS.FormControls.CMSAbstractManager`2.RaiseSaveData(EventArgsType
>   args) at
>   CMS.FormControls.CMSDocumentManager.SaveDocumentInternal(String
>   actionContext)

The site cultutre is US English, but we're in Canada. I didn't set up the culture as en-ca as there is only english and there's no need.

As this doesn't give an error in Chrome, is seems like IE is passing the computer culture to Kentico.

Adding en-ca as a culture isn't an option as it will just cause confusion to the admins.

Comment: Yep, seems like a bug in Kentico. It probably takes the culture from a wrong place. Can you please first try to reproduce it on a vanilla instance of Kentico? If the problem persists, can you send us a detailed bug report through https://devnet.kentico.com/support? Thanks

Comment: Good idea. I'll read through the hotfix notes for V9, and get folks to use Chrome.

I'll check in Edge, see how that works. Dropping IE support from the Admin side doesn't bother me.

Comment: Ok, so a test in Edge, produces the same results. The computer with Edge is set to US, not Canada.

I wonder what's setting the document culture.