# Kentico culture change from en-us to en-ca

Tags: kentico

I'm looking at changing the the single culture from en-us to en-ca. I'm having file upload issues in IE/Edge. See here: [Kentico culture error when uploading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240186/kentico-culture-error-when-uploading-a-file)

I think i need to only have en-ca as the culture, but the site has been fully built on the default en-us. What are the risks involved in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you use culture specific features or not. Typically, only content are based on culture code and in this case, you only need to enable en-ca, and use Translation App to "virtually create" all en-ca content from en-us. (When you do a export for translation, then en-ca would be created automatically from original culture, in your case, you don't need to do any import back).
Other things like media library shouldn't matter. Then see if you have any API calls depending on culture code or not and that's pretty much it.
Once the en-ca is ready, delete all en-us page from the tree, set your default site culture to en-ca and disable en-us culture.

Comment: I'll need to test it out first, before i update the project. Thanks!